# Contextual action mode not closing in API 24 nougat

Tags: android, menu, actionmode, android-7.0-nougat

Since updating all of the google sdks to 24 Actionmode.finish() isn't working anymore. No code changes have been made and even a back press & press on the back arrow in the toolbar have no effect. I'm I missing something or is this a bug?

**EDIT**

My phone is a nexus 6p and is currently not running nougat yet.

Just changed everything back to 23 and actionmode.finish() works so there is def something different:

**Working**:

```
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.4.0'
compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:23.4.0'
compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:23.4.0'
compile 'com.android.support:design:23.4.0'
```

targetSdkVersion 23

compileSdkVersion 23

buildToolsVersion 23

**Not Working:**

```
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:24.2.0'
compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:24.2.0'
compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:24.2.0'
compile 'com.android.support:design:24.2.0'
```

targetSdkVersion 24

compileSdkVersion 24

buildToolsVersion 24.0.2

Comment: I have no problems with `finish()` on an `ActionMode` in [this sample app](https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-omnibus/tree/master/ActionMode/ManualNative) when run on a Nexus 9 with Android 7.0.

Comment: @CommonsWare The post indicates the problem could be the library versions. I am also using the *24* versions and it's not working on Android 5, 6 or 7 (so the android version doesn't seem to matter) - did you try it with the 24 library versions + compileSdk = 24? In your current project you're using older library versions: https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-omnibus/blob/master/ActionMode/ManualNative/app/build.gradle - I couldn't try it with 23 libraries yet, so I can't verify the poster's suspicion.

Comment: @AgentKnopf: "The post indicates the problem could be the library versions" -- that edit was made nearly an hour after my comment, so I did not have that information at the time. "did you try it with the 24 library versions + compileSdk = 24?" -- no. But, since 25 is out, you might try it. On the whole, I avoid `appcompat-v7`.

Comment: @CommonsWare no worries :) - just wanted to see if you had tried it. I'll give 25 a shot though, thank you for the input!